# cannot access to http://localhost:4000 after I map this port number to docker

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

This is my first time to use docker.
I just followed the steps on docker's webiste:
https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#run-the-app 
After I finished every steps, I cannot access `http://localhost:4000` from the browser.(These steps in the link will map 80 to 4000 in the docker)
Here is the configuration for my docker:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND
STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
d204920463a9        firendlyhello       "python app.py"
Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:4000->80/tcp   pensive_bell
```

When I run this app:

```
liyuan.liu@USEUG-98T5N32 MINGW64 ~/test
$ docker run -p 4000:80 firendlyhello
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Then I was trying to open http://localhost:4000 in my browser, but it just said:This site can’t be reached.
This is the app.py content:

```
liyuan.liu@USEUG-98T5N32 MINGW64 ~/test
$ cat app.py
from flask import Flask
from redis import Redis, RedisError
import os
import socket

# Connect to Redis
redis = Redis(host="redis", db=0)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    try:
        visits = redis.incr('counter')
    except RedisError:
        visits = "<i>cannot connect to Redis, counter disabled</i>"

    html = "<h3>Hello {name}!</h3>" \
           "<b>Hostname:</b> {hostname}<br/>" \
           "<b>Visits:</b> {visits}"
    return html.format(name=os.getenv('NAME', "world"), hostname=socket.gethostname(), visits=visits)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Comment: Is it possible that the typo in your command is causing this? The docker image is "friendlyhello" but you typed "firendlyhello"

Comment: If it is because of the typo, the docker command line still display that it is running. If it is running, http://localhost:4000 should work, correct ?

Comment: Firstly, can you access it at `http://localhost:80`? What about `http://0.0.0.0:80` and `http://0.0.0.0:4000`?

Comment: I tried http://localhost:80, http://0.0.0.0:80 and http://0.0.0.0:4000 and http://127.0.0.1:4000, none of them work. ( superuser website always hides "http://" when I type them in the comment......)

Answer (score 1):

Docker configures its own default IP address, which you can see whenever you launch Docker Quickstart Terminal.

Instead of `http://localhost:4000`, `type http://[IP address:4000]`

You can also use this command to find the IP that Docker has configured:

```
docker-machine ip default
```